# Border around 100% body height and width (HTML 4.01 Strict)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Okay, this is driving me crazy right now.

I want to have a border around my document. It should be nicely going around the whole window/viewport. So I define:

```
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

When my document is in quirks mode, this works fine. At least in IE, which is my primary target here. A red border shows up at the very edges of my page, obviously because by predefined CSS `body` and `html` are set to fill the screen.

When going to standards mode by setting a HTML 4.01 strict DOCTYPE, `body` and `html` collapse to the *real* (smaller) size of the content, the border is drawn right through the middle of the screen. So I define:

```
body, html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And I get — scroll bars, scrolling exactly *one pixel* to show the bottom/right borders. However, I want that border visible right away.

Is there a no-bullshit (like "height: 99.9%;", "overflow: hidden;" or "switch back to quirks mode") method to get a border at 100%, without unnecessary scroll bars? IE-only is fine, cross-browser would be better, of course.

Comment: IE-only for intranet application? The only place where you could get 100% of non-IE users? Crazy! :)

Comment: Corporate environments and Firefox are mutually exclusive. At least 99% percent of the time. And until Mozilla finally *gets it* that manual NTLM authentication (or fiddling with about:config on a per client basis) really doesn't cut it, this is going to stay that way.

Comment: Remote configs. http://wetdog.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Along with what Tomalak said, Firefox has consistently had enough printing problems that most companies shy away from it as well.  It's one thing to make a developer do some contortions; it's quite another to make it impossible for the end user to work how they like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As SpliFF already mentioned, the problem is because the default (W3C) [box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) is 'content-box', which results in borders being outside of the `width` and `height`. But you want those to be within the 100% width and height you specified. One workaround is to select the border-box box model, but you can't do that in IE 6 and 7 without reverting to quirks mode.

Another solution works in IE 7, too. Just set `html` and `body` to 100% height and `overflow` to `hidden` to get rid of the window's scrollbars. Then you need to insert an absolutely positioned wrapper div that gets the red border and all content, setting all four [box offset properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) to `0` (so the border sticks to the edges of the viewport) and `overflow` to `auto` (to put the scrollbars inside the wrapper div).

There's only one drawback: IE 6 doesn't support setting both `left` *and* `right` and both `top` *and* `bottom`. The only workaround for this is to use [CSS expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28VS.85%29.aspx) (within a conditional comment) to explicitly set the width and height of the wrapper to the viewport's sizes, minus the width of the border.

To make it easier to see the effect, in the following example I enlarged the border width to 5 pixels:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Border around content</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      border: 5px solid red;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
      width: expression((m=document.documentElement.clientWidth-10)+'px');
      height: expression((m=document.documentElement.clientHeight-10)+'px');
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- just a large div to get scrollbars -->
    <div style="width: 9999px; height: 9999px; background: #ddd"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**P.S.:** I just saw you don't like `overflow: hidden`, hmmm...

---

**Update:** I managed to get around using `overflow: hidden` by faking a border using four divs that stick to the edges of the viewport (you can't just overlay the whole viewport with a full-sized div, as all elements below it wouldn't be accessible any more). It's not a nice solution, but at least the normal scrollbars remain in their original position. I couldn't manage to let IE 6 simulate the fixed positioning using CSS expressions (got problems with the right and bottom divs), but it looked horribly anyway as those expressions are [very expensive](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_6.html) and rendering got tediously slow.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Border around content</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #border-t, #border-b, #border-l, #border-r {
      position: fixed;
      background: red;
      z-index: 9999;
    }

    #border-t {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 5px;
    }

    #border-b {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 5px;
    }

    #border-l {
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 5px;
    }

    #border-r {
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- just a large div to get scrollbars -->
  <div style="width: 9999px; height: 9999px; background: #ddd"></div>
  <div id="border-t"></div><div id="border-b"></div>
  <div id="border-l"></div><div id="border-r"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1, at least that's a decent explanation. Yeah, the `overflow: hidden` is a bit hacky, but I guess there's no way around it. Looks like my original request is impossible to fulfill, but that's an answer, too.

Comment: PS: Nice work-around in your update! I'd give a second +1 if I could. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: I did it for you. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You'll love this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<style>
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
body {
    display: table-row;
}
#wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.test.dev.arc.net.au/100-percent-border.html

I figured since tables keep a lot of "quirky" behavior even under standards mode they might be the solution. Turning the HTML element into a table is pretty funny though.

Before marking this down for not working in IE6 consider that's a very trivial issue to fix. The point is that using the table drawing algorithm is the solution, and a pure CSS solution is also possible:

```
<table class="outer"><tr><td class="inner"> ...page content...
```

Comment: The only solution on the page that actually works and it gets marked down?? WTF?

Comment: Hmm.. guess because it doesn't work in IE6? but then that's what IE7-js is for.

Comment: this works **to an extent**. if you have multiple divs positioned relatively, for whatever reason the first div will take up the great majority of the space and every other div will only take up a sliver of the screen, instead of each page taking up one entire page :/ why is this?!?!?!

Answer (score 3):

Until CSS3 gives us inside borders and box-model switching you need two divs. The first to give the 100% height and the second to provide the border. Otherwise the border goes on the outside of the 100% height (ie, 1px+100%+1px)

BTW. You should collect some stats before going "IE only". IE does not have the marketshare it once did. Anywhere between 10 - 30% of your users may be on other browsers.

Comment: It's an Intranet application. It's quite safe to say that it is IE only. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using only the html and body elements (no need for nested divs). It takes advantage of the special behaviour of the HTML element (it can't have an outer border so it must shrink to display it).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {padding:0; margin:0; border:5px solid red;}
body {height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the "special properties" of the HTML element in this regard. Good to know.

Comment: It does not seem to work in standards mode, though. The html height collapses again, and setting it to 100% results in a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: You must be using Internet Exploiter. It works with 4.01 Strict on FF so you're probably seeing a browser bug.

Answer (score 1):

It also a bit ugly, but giving the body

```
position:relative;
top:-1px;
left:-1px;
```

worked for me.

Comment: That's worth a try as well. And it's just *a bit* ugly, not serious.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting borders for the html element. The body element is only as high as it needs to but, as far as I remember, the html element takes the whole space (it's where you should set your background, too).

I'm not sure how borders look, I usually only set backgrounds.

Comment: Not working, same problem. The HTML element is also only as high/wide as in needs to be when the document is in standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

border is out of 100% size. Try `padding: -1px` or `margin: -1px`.

Comment: negative margin pulled the border out of the document, padding must be positive in the CSS specification.