# How do you make an HTML page fit the web browser size?

Tags: asp.net, html, updatepanel

I'm trying to make a web page that only has content within the page itself. The page itself should not have scrollbars (although individual parts should have scrollbars). I want it to look very similar to how the Java API is laid out here, http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/, but without frames.

The page needs to also be able to dynamically load content.

Right now, I'm trying to get it to work with the ASP !UpdatePanel for the dynamically loaded content and a div for the sizing and panel display, but the panels never cover the screen. For example, I'll have:

```
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 100%; border-style: groove; border-width: medium;">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="TOC" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Panel ID="Display" Height="100%" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
      </asp>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

But this doesn't cover the entire height of the panel. The width is fine. But it creates a small border at the top of the page, then this expands when content gets filled in on a button press. Then the border changes. I'd much prefer the border remain static.

Is there anyway to do this with divs?

EDIT: I just tried this in Firefox and it worked perfectly (excluding the .NET specific things since I was on Linux without the ability to create ASP.NET pages). I need this to work with Internet Explorer 7 though (and probably Internet Explorer 6 too). Is there any neat hack around IE7 completely ignoring the css height property?

Comment: 1) Don't add these styles to your HTML, but put them in a separate block or file. 2) I don't know if your current example is all right in Firefox and Chrome, as the bottom part of the border is invisible (below the fold) 3) When filling the inner div with contents that are too wide to be completely visible inside the viewport *and* too high to fit above the fold, the horizontal scroll bar is pushed down and I have to scroll to the bottom of the page before I can scroll horizontally. 3) In IE, do you need standards mode (as the solution is a bit easier when I can fall back to quirks mode)?

Comment: I'm going to remove the styles into a separate css file after I figure out what I'm doing. I'm relatively new to web development, so I'm not trying to overcomplicate it. To get around the contents being too far down the screen, I switched height to about 98.5% and it seemed to work. I believe that the site will only be run on IE, but I'd like it to at least kind of work on other browsers just because I don't want to make another site that's only compatible with IE. So likely I will want to stick with standards mode.

Comment: Looks very much like [Border around 100% body height and width (HTML 4.01 Strict)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886809) and [IE6 “frame” layout with 100% height and scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857412).

Comment: you should set the style to the form as well as the body.

<form style="height: 100%;">

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the only sure way to achieve this is with some javascript.

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      // Wait for the HTML to finish loading.
  var resize = function() {
    var height = $(window).height();  // Get the height of the browser window area.
    var element = $("body");          // Find the element to resize.
    element.height(height);           // Set the element's height.
  }
  resize();
  $(window).bind("resize", resize);
});
```

If you're covering multiple browsers, you may need to tweak this a bit.

Comment: I couldn't use jQuery, but the same concept worked. http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow for the IE specific things.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `width:100%` CSS property on an element, the element's parent needs to have a defined height.

The parent `div` of your main div is `body`. So you need to apply `height: 100%` to the body tag:

```
<body style="height: 100%">
```

EDIT: to make sure nothing overflows, you also want to apply `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to `body`.

Comment: Try adding `height:100%` to the `<html>` tag: `<style type="text/css">html { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin:0; }</style>`

This might fix it for IE