# ASP NET scroll bars on full screen web page?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, .net-core

[image]

all the asp dotnet new projects make full screen web pages that are not really full screen but two or three pixels shorter then full screen so scroll bars show up and the page wiggles when use scroll wheel

how can change this page to FIT the browser?

thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=linux

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in the stack over flow itself, the solution was set the size of the web page using java script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      // Wait for the HTML to finish loading.
  var resize = function() {
    var height = $(window).height();  // Get the height of the browser window area.
    var element = $("body");          // Find the element to resize.
    element.height(height);           // Set the element's height.
  }
  resize();
  $(window).bind("resize", resize);
});
```

[How do you make an HTML page fit the web browser size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135803/how-do-you-make-an-html-page-fit-the-web-browser-size)