# Div with 100% height has an small margin on bottom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem that I am struggling to solve on IE8. I need a 100% height div but everything that I have tried doesn't solve the problem.

You can see the problem here: http://gyazo.com/71ffde560df4d3f87c0fb55a92ef8313

[image]

or reproduce here: http://maahes.ninja/ie/ie.html

Problem is that little white margin in the bottom of the page, and this only happens on ie8 (it's ok on ie9). I was able to solve it by removing the doctype yet that fixes the problem, but breaks all the application.

CSS:

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,
a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,
del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,
small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,
b,u,i,center,
dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,
fieldset,form,label,legend,
table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,
article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,
time,mark,audio,video{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body { 
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background:#9699FF;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Sorry for not adding more images / links but I have no reputation for that.

Comment: It's okay that you didn't include images; code is infinitely better.

Comment: I don't see the margin using ie11 set to ie8 standards and mode

Comment: @Pete I tested using real ie8 (inside a VM but still) and problem is there :(

Comment: http://www.allwebcafe.com/blog/time-to-drop-support-for-ie8/

Comment: It seems like it's related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886809/border-around-100-body-height-and-width-html-4-01-strict

Comment: I would love to just drop support for ie8, but it's not my call here. @PaulRedmond from the link you posted, it is changing the doctype and by doing so, the app I am working on doesn't work anymore (Cordova). That's why I need to keep the html5 doctype but (try) to fix the problem. Seems like an impossible task, about to give up.

Comment: Fwiw, also tested from js to try to make it use all the space, but seems like a ie8 render issue so nothing I do will fix the problem :(

Comment: There's a gray border that goes around the whole page in ie8. I don't think you can get rid of that.

The only white border I see looks like it might just be the top border of your developer tools box. If you close the developer tools, do you still see the white border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no white margin on the screenshot you shared. What you see is an embossy-stiled Windows GUI-Element - the border of IE8s browser window.

You could try to verify this by adding a red background to the `<html>` tag.

```
html {
  background: red;
}
```

This way you should see a red background, if your div had any margin-like effec on it.

I testet your link on my IE8/WinXP virtual machine and there was no extra margin. (see: [Screenshot](http://share.pho.to/9YhcN))

I enlarged the lower left corner of my screenshot ([click here](http://share.pho.to/9Yhcy)) so the inner window-border is more clearly to be seen.

Comment: you are right! thanks alot :) will mark this as the correct answer